# What chsh did when I type `chsh -s SHELL` and how to go back to previous SHELL?

Tags: shell, freebsd, chsh

I have mistakenly setting my user login shell to some unknown directory:([1].
Now, I can't login to this user.
Every time I try to ssh, it always failed as if I enter the wrong password.
I try to login using root and do `su --shell=/bin/tcsh username` and I got

```
su: /path/to/shell/i/set/previously: permission denied
```

To be clear, `/path/to/shell/i/set/previously` point to some directory, not to shell executable. I've tried to change my login shell on `/etc/passwd` back to `/bin/tcsh` with no luck:(. Always got the same permission denied error:(.

Now, I wonder what chsh did that make me unable to login even after I change the entry on `/etc/passwd`. Also, how do I get back my previous shell (`/bin/tcsh`)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as root and use:

```
chpass username
```

You'll be in a vi buffer with the user settings.  Change the shell to /bin/tcsh and  Bob's your uncle.

As for why, these settings are actually held in **/etc/master.passwd**.  /etc/passwd is generated from that file.  [Read The Fine Manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=passwd&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE) for more.

Comment: Unknown command “chpass”    ...  and how do you do this if the root user is the one you changed?

Comment: @endolith  Are you using freebsd?